# React Three Fiber box from normal to wireframe transition when scrolling

Tags: reactjs, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

I'm trying to create a **box** in **react fiber** whose position is fixed to the background. Also there are two sections, in the first section the box has the mesh set to Standard Material and when **scrolled** it transitions to the next section and it changes it's look and transitions to wireframe look.

[example](https://codepen.io/ste-vg/full/GRooLza)(This is the website i get the idea from, and i'm trying to create something similar, but the source code is in plane javaScript)

```
// there are 3 parts to this
//
// Scene:           Setups and manages threejs rendering
// loadModel:       Loads the 3d obj file
// setupAnimation:  Creates all the GSAP 
//                  animtions and scroll triggers 
//
// first we call loadModel, once complete we call
// setupAnimation which creates a new Scene

class Scene
{
    constructor(model)
    {
        this.views = [
            { bottom: 0, height: 1 },
            { bottom: 0, height: 0 }
        ];
        
        this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
            antialias: true,
            alpha: true
        });
        
        this.renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        this.renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
        this.renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap;
        this.renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);

        document.body.appendChild( this.renderer.domElement );
        
        // scene

        this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
        
        for ( var ii = 0; ii < this.views.length; ++ ii ) {

            var view = this.views[ ii ];
            var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 2000 );
            camera.position.fromArray([0, 0, 180] );
            camera.layers.disableAll();
            camera.layers.enable( ii );
            view.camera = camera;
            camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 5, 0));
        }
        
        //light

        this.light = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff, 0.75 );
        this.light.position.z = 150;
        this.light.position.x = 70;
        this.light.position.y = -20;
        this.scene.add( this.light );

        this.softLight = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0xffffff, 1.5 );
        this.scene.add(this.softLight)

        // group

        this.onResize();
        window.addEventListener( 'resize', this.onResize, false );
        
        var edges = new THREE.EdgesGeometry( model.children[ 0 ].geometry );
        let line = new THREE.LineSegments( edges );
        line.material.depthTest = false;
        line.material.opacity = 0.5;
        line.material.transparent = true;
        line.position.x = 0.5;
        line.position.z = -1;
        line.position.y = 0.2;  
        
        this.modelGroup = new THREE.Group();
        
        model.layers.set( 0 );
        line.layers.set( 1 );
            
        this.modelGroup.add(model);
        this.modelGroup.add(line);
        this.scene.add(this.modelGroup);
    }
    
    render = () =>
    {
        for ( var ii = 0; ii < this.views.length; ++ ii ) {

            var view = this.views[ ii ];
            var camera = view.camera;

            var bottom = Math.floor( this.h * view.bottom );
            var height = Math.floor( this.h * view.height );

            this.renderer.setViewport( 0, 0, this.w, this.h );
            this.renderer.setScissor( 0, bottom, this.w, height );
            this.renderer.setScissorTest( true );

            camera.aspect = this.w / this.h;
            this.renderer.render( this.scene, camera );
        }
    }
    
    onResize = () => 
    {
        this.w = window.innerWidth;
        this.h = window.innerHeight;
        
        for ( var ii = 0; ii < this.views.length; ++ ii ) {
            var view = this.views[ ii ];
            var camera = view.camera;
            camera.aspect = this.w / this.h;
            let camZ = (screen.width - (this.w * 1)) / 3;
            camera.position.z = camZ < 180 ? 180 : camZ;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
        }

        this.renderer.setSize( this.w, this.h );        
        this.render();
    }
}

function loadModel() 
{
    gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);
    gsap.registerPlugin(DrawSVGPlugin);
    gsap.set('#line-length', {drawSVG: 0})
    gsap.set('#line-wingspan', {drawSVG: 0})
    gsap.set('#circle-phalange', {drawSVG: 0})
    
    var object;

    function onModelLoaded() {
        object.traverse( function ( child ) {
            let mat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0x171511, specular: 0xD0CBC7, shininess: 5, flatShading: true } );
            child.material = mat;
        });

        setupAnimation(object);
    }

    var manager = new THREE.LoadingManager( onModelLoaded );
    manager.onProgress = ( item, loaded, total ) => console.log( item, loaded, total );

    var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader( manager );
    loader.load( 'https://assets.codepen.io/557388/1405+Plane_1.obj', function ( obj ) { object = obj; });
}

function setupAnimation(model)
{
    let scene = new Scene(model);
    let plane = scene.modelGroup;
    
    gsap.fromTo('canvas',{x: "50%", autoAlpha: 0},  {duration: 1, x: "0%", autoAlpha: 1});
    gsap.to('.loading', {autoAlpha: 0})
    gsap.to('.scroll-cta', {opacity: 1})
    gsap.set('svg', {autoAlpha: 1})
    
    let tau = Math.PI * 2;

    gsap.set(plane.rotation, {y: tau * -.25});
    gsap.set(plane.position, {x: 80, y: -32, z: -60});
    
    scene.render();
    
    var sectionDuration = 1;
    gsap.fromTo(scene.views[1], 
        {   height: 1, bottom: 0 }, 
        {
            height: 0, bottom: 1,
            ease: 'none',
            scrollTrigger: {
              trigger: ".blueprint",
              scrub: true,
              start: "bottom bottom",
              end: "bottom top"
            }
        })
    
    gsap.fromTo(scene.views[1], 
        {   height: 0, bottom: 0 }, 
        {
            height: 1, bottom: 0,
            ease: 'none',
            scrollTrigger: {
              trigger: ".blueprint",
              scrub: true,
              start: "top bottom",
              end: "top top"
            }
        })
    
    gsap.to('.ground', {
        y: "30%",
        scrollTrigger: {
          trigger: ".ground-container",
          scrub: true,
          start: "top bottom",
          end: "bottom top"
        }
    })
    
    gsap.from('.clouds', {
        y: "25%",
        scrollTrigger: {
          trigger: ".ground-container",
          scrub: true,
          start: "top bottom",
          end: "bottom top"
        }
    })
    
    gsap.to('#line-length', {
        drawSVG: 100,
        scrollTrigger: {
          trigger: ".length",
          scrub: true,
          start: "top bottom",
          end: "top top"
        }
    })
    
    gsap.to('#line-wingspan', {
        drawSVG: 100,
        scrollTrigger: {
          trigger: ".wingspan",
          scrub: true,
          start: "top 25%",
          end: "bottom 50%"
        }
    })  
    
    gsap.to('#circle-phalange', {
        drawSVG: 100,
        scrollTrigger: {
          trigger: ".phalange",
          scrub: true,
          start: "top 50%",
          end: "bottom 100%"
        }
    })
    
    gsap.to('#line-length', {
        opacity: 0,
        drawSVG: 0,
        scrollTrigger: {
          trigger: ".length",
          scrub: true,
          start: "top top",
          end: "bottom top"
        }
    })
    
    gsap.to('#line-wingspan', {
        opacity: 0,
        drawSVG: 0,
        scrollTrigger: {
          trigger: ".wingspan",
          scrub: true,
          start: "top top",
          end: "bottom top"
        }
    })  
    
    gsap.to('#circle-phalange', {
        opacity: 0,
        drawSVG: 0,
        scrollTrigger: {
          trigger: ".phalange",
          scrub: true,
          start: "top top",
          end: "bottom top"
        }
    })
    
    let tl = new gsap.timeline(
    {
        onUpdate: scene.render,
        scrollTrigger: {
          trigger: ".content",
          scrub: true,
          start: "top top",
          end: "bottom bottom"
        },
        defaults: {duration: sectionDuration, ease: 'power2.inOut'}
    });
    
    let delay = 0;
    
    tl.to('.scroll-cta', {duration: 0.25, opacity: 0}, delay)
    tl.to(plane.position, {x: -10, ease: 'power1.in'}, delay)
    
    delay += sectionDuration;
    
    tl.to(plane.rotation, {x: tau * .25, y: 0, z: -tau * 0.05, ease: 'power1.inOut'}, delay)
    tl.to(plane.position, {x: -40, y: 0, z: -60, ease: 'power1.inOut'}, delay)
    
    delay += sectionDuration;
    
    tl.to(plane.rotation, {x: tau * .25, y: 0,  z: tau * 0.05, ease: 'power3.inOut'}, delay)
    tl.to(plane.position, {x: 40, y: 0, z: -60, ease: 'power2.inOut'}, delay)
    
    delay += sectionDuration;
    
    tl.to(plane.rotation, {x: tau * .2, y: 0, z: -tau * 0.1, ease: 'power3.inOut'}, delay)
    tl.to(plane.position, {x: -40, y: 0, z: -30, ease: 'power2.inOut'}, delay)
    
    delay += sectionDuration;
    
    tl.to(plane.rotation, { x: 0, z: 0, y: tau * .25}, delay)
    tl.to(plane.position, { x: 0, y: -10, z: 50}, delay)
    
    delay += sectionDuration;
    delay += sectionDuration;
    
    tl.to(plane.rotation, {x: tau * 0.25, y: tau *.5, z: 0, ease:'power4.inOut'}, delay)
    tl.to(plane.position, {z: 30, ease:'power4.inOut'}, delay)
    
    delay += sectionDuration;
    
    tl.to(plane.rotation, {x: tau * 0.25, y: tau *.5, z: 0, ease:'power4.inOut'}, delay)
    tl.to(plane.position, {z: 60, x: 30, ease:'power4.inOut'}, delay)
    
    delay += sectionDuration;
    
    tl.to(plane.rotation, {x: tau * 0.35, y: tau *.75, z: tau * 0.6, ease:'power4.inOut'}, delay)
    tl.to(plane.position, {z: 100, x: 20, y: 0, ease:'power4.inOut'}, delay)
    
    delay += sectionDuration;
    
    tl.to(plane.rotation, {x: tau * 0.15, y: tau *.85, z: -tau * 0, ease: 'power1.in'}, delay)
    tl.to(plane.position, {z: -150, x: 0, y: 0, ease: 'power1.inOut'}, delay)
    
    delay += sectionDuration;
    
    tl.to(plane.rotation, {duration: sectionDuration, x: -tau * 0.05, y: tau, z: -tau * 0.1, ease: 'none'}, delay)
    tl.to(plane.position, {duration: sectionDuration, x: 0, y: 30, z: 320, ease: 'power1.in'}, delay)
    
    tl.to(scene.light.position, {duration: sectionDuration, x: 0, y: 0, z: 0}, delay)
}

loadModel();
```

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FpgL4.png)
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mr5jz.png)

I tried to create the effect by adding 2 boxes on top of each other with the view property from react drei but while resizing the height of the first.

[What i tried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBanZ.png)